# Changing images in cells for UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have four different cells that I am trying to add images to and every time that I change the image it adds the image to each cell. I'm trying to add separate images for each cell, but I'm not sure how to do it. Any help would be great! Here's my code:

```
if ([singletonObj.tempChangelistColor isEqualToString:@"red"]) {

            self.layer.contents = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"red.png"].CGImage;

        }else if([singletonObj.tempChangelistColor isEqualToString:@"yellow"]){

          self.layer.contents = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"yellow.png"].CGImage;

        }else if([singletonObj.tempChangelistColor isEqualToString:@"green"]){

            self.layer.contents = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"green.png"].CGImage;
        }else{

            self.layer.contents = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"shop_deal.png"].CGImage;

        }
```

It's at the bottom of the code with the **shop_deal.png**.

Comment: Base the color/image on the indexPath of the cell.

Comment: Code you have placed is not clear. Update your question. Four different cell means "custom cell" are you using ?

Comment: You wanted 4 different colours for 4 cells or ?

Comment: Why are you using this statement? [singletonObj.tempChangelistColor isEqualToString:@"yellow"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you exactly know the cell no. of which you want to change the image then this will help you.

```
NSIndexPath *cellIndex = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:3 inSection:0]; // suppose cell no is 3 in section 0
UITableViewCell *cell = [_youtTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:cellIndex];

cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"shop_deal.png"];
```

**Hope this helps.**

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CellID";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        cell.imageView.image = [self getImageForCell];
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        cell.imageView.image = [self getImageForCell];
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 2) {
        cell.imageView.image = [self getImageForCell];
    }
    else (indexPath.row == 3) {
        cell.imageView.image = [self getImageForCell];
    }
    return cell;
}
- (UIImage *)getImageForCell{

    UIImage *returnImage;

    if ([singletonObj.tempChangelistColor isEqualToString:@"red"]) {
        returnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"red.png"];
    }
    else if ([singletonObj.tempChangelistColor isEqualToString:@"yellow"]){
        returnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yellow.png"];
    }
    else if([singletonObj.tempChangelistColor isEqualToString:@"green"]){
        returnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"green.png"];
    }
    else{
        returnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"shop_deal.png"];
    }
    return returnImage;
}
```

Comment: This is the same code posted by the OP - it does not answer the question. He wants a different image in each cell. This code puts the same image in all cells.

Comment: Update my above code snippet - The requirement is not clear as to how this 4 different images will be picked for different cells as the image selection is dependent on 'tempChangelistColor' variable.